# Does `std::make_shared<POD>()` value initialize my POD?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

Does `std::make_shared<POD>()` value initialize my POD?

If yes, is this a guaranteed by the standard?

If no (as I suspect), is there a way to do this? I guess `std::make_shared<POD>(POD())` would do but is that what I should be doing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it's value intialized, and this is guaranteed by the standard:

**§20.7.2.2.6,2:** (about `make_shared`)

> Effects: Allocates memory suitable for an object of type `T` and constructs an object in that memory via the placement new expression `::new (pv) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`.

And **§5.3.4,15:**

> A new-expression that creates an object of type T initializes that object as follows:
>   — If the new-initializer is omitted, the object is default-initialized (8.5); if no initialization is performed, the object has indeterminate value.
>   — **Otherwise, the new-initializer is interpreted according to the initialization rules of 8.5 for directinitialization.**

So it's direct-initialized as in `new POD()`.

**§8.5,16:**

> The semantics of initializers are as follows. [...]
>   — If the initializer is (), **the object is value-initialized.**

Answer (score 8):

> Does `std::make_shared<POD>()` value initialize my POD?

Yes.

> If yes, is this a guaranteed by the standard?

C++11 20.7.2.2.6/2 specifies that it "constructs an object in that memory
via the placement new expression `::new (pv) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`". With no arguments, that will be `::new (pv) T()`, which value-initialises the object.

Answer (score 8):

> Does `std::make_shared<POD>()` value initialize my POD?

**Yes**, it does. Paragraph 20.7.2.2.6/2 about `std::make_shared<>()` says that:

> 2 *Effects*: Allocates memory suitable for an object of type `T` and constructs an object in that memory
>   via the placement `new` expression `::new (pv) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`.

In case no arguments are passed, this means your data structure is constructed this way:

```
::new(pv) T()
```

This is guaranteed to yield direct-initialization because of paragraph 5.3.4/15:

> A new-expression that creates an object of type `T` initializes that object as follows:
>
> — If the *new-initializer* is omitted, the object is default-initialized (8.5); if no initialization is performed,
>   the object has indeterminate value.
>
> — **Otherwise, the *new-initializer* is interpreted according to the initialization rules of 8.5 for direct-initialization.**

In your case, the *new-initializer* is present and it is `()`. And direct-initialization with an empty set of parentheses is specified to yield *value-initialization* in paragraph 8.5/11:

> An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., `()`, shall be **value-initialized**. [...]